# Are there examples of Hebrew Slaves in the Gemmorah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, slave-serve-eved-avadim, mishpatim

Are there examples of Hebrew Slaves mentioned in the Gemmorah?

Names of the slaves or their masters, the amounts paid, the terms served etc?

*(I recall a couple of Eved K'naani like Tavi, but can't recall a Hebrew one).*

Answer (score 4):

No, there are not. Yovel had ceased to be operative centuries earlier and the rules of Jewish slaves became inoperative with it ([Rambam, Avadim 1:10](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1363800/jewish/Avadim-Chapter-One.htm)).

> The institution of a Hebrew maid-servant and that of a Hebrew servant
>   is not practiced except in the time when the Jubilee year is observed.
>   This applies both to a Hebrew servant who sells himself, and to one
>   who is sold by the court. We have already explained when the
>   observance of the Jubilee year was nullified.

[Rambam Sefer Zeraim Hilchot Shemita 10:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1007174/jewish/Shemita-Chapter-10.htm)

> From the time the tribes of Reuven and Gad and half the tribe of
>   Menasheh were exiled, [the observance] of the Jubilee year ceased, as
>   [implied by Leviticus 25:10]: "You shall proclaim freedom throughout
>   the land to all of its inhabitants." [One can infer that this
>   commandment applies only] when all of its inhabitants are dwelling
>   within it. [Moreover,] they may not be intermingled, one tribe with
>   another, but rather each tribe is dwelling in its appropriate place.

Comment: I thought Yovel was kept during the second temple times. Anything exemplary from the writings maybe?

Comment: @AlBerko There are those who say that the counting of the Yovel year was maintained, but it was not observed fully.